# product of two chi-squared distributed variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random

What is the expected value of the product of two chi-squared distributed variables (E[XY] where X and Y are chi-squared distributed random variables)?

Comment: Are the both variables independent?

Comment: Not in general, if they are independent then I guess E[XY]=E[X]E[Y], right?

Comment: Yes if the are independent, then expected value of the product is the product of the expected values.

Comment: Well, can someone tell me if the product of two chi-squared random variables (dependent) is chi-squared distributed itself? I suppose It is! and what it the degree of freedom for $XY$

Comment: @seyran it's not. Just like the product of normal random variables is not normal.